# Laravel Elixir doesn't minify

Tags: laravel-elixir, gulp-uglify

I want to minify all the js file from public/js folder and version into the public/build folder. Inside the js folder I have  two folder **custom**(contains self created js file) & **vendor** (contains 3rd party library file).

I'm able to create version of all the files inside both the folders,but files are not getting minified.

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
mix.scripts([
    'custom/top.js',
    'custom/commonData.js',
], 'public/js/common.js', 'public/js');

mix.version([
    'js/common.js',
    'public/js/**/*.js'
]);
```

I have run above snippet with "gulp --production"

Please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your gulpfile should look like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('es6-promise').polyfill();

elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.scripts([
        'custom/top.js',
        'custom/commonData.js',
    ], 'public/js/common.js', 'public/js');

    mix.version([
        'js/common.js',
        'public/js/**/*.js'
    ]);
});
```